# Which JRE 7 version should I use on a linux server in production ? Is it always the latest one?

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-7

Should I always use the latest JRE version of Java 7 for a ubuntu production server ? Or should I be careful while upgrading between these minor versions too ?

Does the same rule apply to while making a choice between minor versions of Tomcat7 server?

I'm  asking this in context of making a choice only amongst the minor versions of Java 7. Also  please mind I'm asking this for a **PRODUCTION server** so I need extra carefulness.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about administration or software configuration rather than programming.  It might be more appropriate on [Super User](http://superuser.com), [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), or [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Comment: @cHao: could this be  moved to appropriate place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the latest one, but at the same time, i would suggest to move your updates first on a stage server , test them thoroughly be fore moving to production. This is because, many time the project code uses library/jars who are compatible only with certain version of JRE, and upgrading JRE version might break them. So, either you need to update those library /jar as well or you live with current JRE version.

If those jars are not being maintained, you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is a security issue; the minors are almost always security updates. Use the latest of whichever JRE (Oracle, OpenJDK) you choose.

Comment: ohk so I dont have to much worry about while upgrading that whether or not my app would be compatible with new JRE7 or new Tomcat7 minor version Or there won't be any issues? Should I just upgrade as soon as I see a new minor version out there ?